# how to call http request immediately again after completion

Tags: angular, rxjs

This HTTP call is long polling. My current solution is:

```
interval(5000).subscribe(() => {
    if (!this.isLoading) {
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.httpService.getEvents()
          .pipe(finalize(() => this.isLoading = false))
          .subscribe((r) => {
          // do something
        });
      }
    });
```

But I want to reduce the latency when the last http call is done. How to call this HTTP request in finalize again at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you could use `switchMap` to cancel any pending requests (requests that take more than 5s) or [`exhaustMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-exhaustMap) to wait until the active request completes while ignoring any subsequent emissions from `interval` (it depends on what you want to achieve).

```
timer(0, 5000)
  .pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => this.httpService.getEvents()),
    take(1),
    repeat(),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: Good solution. I also want to issue a new request once the previous is completed and do not wait for 5 seconds. Is it possible to achieve it?

Comment: Then it's a little more complicated and you'll have to use `timer` instead of `interval` that emits without the first delay.